# By using Paramiko module in Python how can I edit a file on Linux server?

Tags: python, ssh, centos, paramiko

Suppose I made a file using Paramiko module in CentOS and accessing it from a Python script in Windows:

```
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command("touch Hello")
```

Then how can I write something and save the file?

```
print "hello,world"
```

Please help me I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SFTP](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html) to upload the file contents. Do not try to hack this with shell commands.

```
transport = paramiko.Transport(("host", 22))
transport.connect(username = "username", password = "password")
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

f = sftp.open("/path/to/remote/file", "wb")
f.write("hello,world")
f.close()
```